# In R, to apply the same process to a lot of subsets, do we group or loop?

Tags: r

I've got a task to perform some minor maintenance to an R script, upgrading it from processing a single customer/product/packaging at once, to multiple. I've never written a single line of R and the syntax is readable to me but fairly foreign

The R script looks like:

```
  
raw<-dbFetch(dbSubmitQuery("
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE company = 1 and product = 1 and pack = 1
"))
                                                                                                                                           
#Data with just req dates and del qtys
df = subset(raw, select = c(DelDate, DelQty) )

#sum del qty by date
df<- aggregate(df["DelQty"], by=df["DelDate"], sum)

#add missing dates
df<- df %>%
  mutate(DelDate = as.Date(DelDate)) %>%
  complete(DelDate = seq.Date(min(DelDate), max(DelDate), by="day"))

df[is.na(df)] = 0

df$date2<- floor_date( df$DelDate - days(1), "week") + days(1)

df<- ddply(df, .(date2), summarize, DelQty=sum(DelQty))

df$week = format(df$date2, format="%Y-%U")

tsweek_forecast<- ts(df$DelQty, frequency = 52)

h <- 2

fit_Arima_future <- Arima(tsweek_forecast, order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(0,1,0))

ARIMA_forecast_future <- forecast(fit_Arima_future, h=h)$mean

# and then some output back to db here..
```

It produces a single forecast for one customer/product/pack

If I were to change the query at the head of the script so that it looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE company in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and product in (1,2,3,4) and pack In(1,2)
```

How would I then modify the R so that it produces a data set of "company, product, pack, forecast" (80 items in the data set - 10 co's x 4 products x 2 packs)

..would I do this as a repeated set of ops in a loop (where I've determined the distinct customer/prod/pack tuples first and loop per tuple) or is it done by some grouping facility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that you want to apply to each group and use `group_by` to apply.

```
library(dplyr)

apply_fun <- function(raw) {
  df = subset(raw, select = c(DelDate, DelQty) )
  #sum del qty by date
  df<- aggregate(df["DelQty"], by=df["DelDate"], sum)
  #add missing dates
  df<- df %>%
    mutate(DelDate = as.Date(DelDate)) %>%
    complete(DelDate = seq.Date(min(DelDate), max(DelDate), by="day"))
  df[is.na(df)] = 0
  df$date2<- floor_date( df$DelDate - days(1), "week") + days(1)
  df<- ddply(df, .(date2), summarize, DelQty=sum(DelQty))
  df$week = format(df$date2, format="%Y-%U")
  tsweek_forecast<- ts(df$DelQty, frequency = 52)
  h <- 2
  fit_Arima_future <- Arima(tsweek_forecast, order=c(1,0,1), seasonal=c(0,1,0))
  ARIMA_forecast_future <- forecast(fit_Arima_future, h=h)$mean
  ARIMA_forecast_future
}

data <-dbFetch(dbSubmitQuery("
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE company in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and product in (1,2,3,4) and pack in (1,2)
"))

result <- data %>% 
            group_by(customer, product, packaging) %>%  
            summarise(predict = apply_fun(cur_data()))
```

Which can also be written with `by` as -

```
by(data, data[c('customer', 'product', 'packaging')], apply_fun)
```

Comment: Got it. I think the updated answer might help.

Comment: Awesome, will give it a go and let you know

Comment: I got *Error: `cur_data()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.* but I think I was able to resolve it by putting `dplyr::` before summarize

Comment: Yes, that is because you also have `plyr` loaded along with `dplyr` which masks the `summarise` function.

Comment: One last question (sorry).. if ` forecast(fit_Arima_future, h=h)$mean` seems to return me two values e.g. the group that is returned has `Company; <int> 1, 1` and `ProductId: <int> 1, 1` and `Pack: <int> 2, 2` and `predict: <dbl> 1234, 5678` - I assume that the `forecast(fit_Arima_future, h=h)$mean` returns something like an array of size two.. How do I just pick the second number (so my group is just 66/1/2/5678) ?

Comment: You can subset the data using `[]`. So to pick second number do `forecast(fit_Arima_future, h=h)$mean[2]`

Comment: Cool, so R is 1-based.. Maybe I should read a "how to R for C# devs" :D, thanks!